# Limit panning in Bing Maps

Tags: bing-maps, pan

I'm developing a map for a project that has multiple location but they're all in the same county/ city.

How do I limit the user from panning outside the county/ city in Bing Maps?
I know that I can use disablePanning in map options but how do I set it the City boundaries only?

Comment: Would something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327665/restrict-the-min-max-zoom-on-a-bing-map-with-v7-of-the-ajax-control?lq=1) help

Comment: Thanks dassouki, that helps, However what I need to do is to limit the panning, not the zooming. See example using Google Maps [here](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_range.htm) (you will have to zoom out and then try to pan- you will see that for example you can't reach America by panning)

Comment: Anyone pleaaaaase